# Passing Value from servlet to JSP file without RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is it possible to pass value of variable from Servlet in to JSP. Say i have a JSP something like welcome.jsp and I have some variable initialized in welcome.java servlet.

When I run welcome.jsp it should take value from welcome.java and display it on page.

When I set the RequestDispatcher and forward it its still going to show the servlet URL.But I want the URL to be JSP file.But the Variable I display in JSP file should be taken from servlet.

Comment: Also read here about different scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718683/814702

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can archive it using session attributes.

**.java**

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("attrName", "value");
```

request is instance of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

**.jsp**

```
${attrName}
```

---

To get more about session attributes, read [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). You can set attribute of any type.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("attrName", new ArrayList());
```

Comment: I have a List of Records To be Displayed What you will do in this Case

Comment: I am Sure your method works.But Storing Array in session is not a good Idea I guess.Sorry If I am Wrong.

Comment: @user1973669, it is only right way to store user session data on server.

Comment: You could also use request scoped attributes 'request.setAttribute();' if you don't need the passed values maintained on the session scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the variable in Session and redirect the user to welcome.jsp page.