# Redirecting from a servlet to an error page

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

I am currently doing an assignment in university, and one of the final tasks is to add a re-direct to a servlet that takes the user to an error page if a form doesn't contain any information that can be linked to the database using the string below.

```
String selectSQL = "select * from video_recordings where director = '"+directorsearch+"';";
```

I have it set up so that it prints the relevant contents of the database, with an in-line error, but CSS screws it up an actual page would look better. Any ideas on the best method of doing this as re-directs aren't overly efficient.

Many thanks

Comment: related - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632252/servlet-redirect-to-same-page-with-error-message?rq=1

Comment: You're going two ways with this question. I have the idea that you're trying to run away from a problem (not being able to properly display a feedback message "director not found") by replacing it with the solution of a generic error page which is only to be used in true exceptional cases. What is it that you truly want to achieve with this question?