# Hitting back browser button creates many get requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, firefox, devise

When I hit the back browser button, the server receives a bunch of get requests for the same resource. The one I'm going back to.

I tried it in both Chrome and Firefox and it happens on both, so I'm guessing is not a browser issue. I'm running Rails 4 on Ubuntu.

Other than the standard gems Rails installs by default, the only other gem I'm using is Devise. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313788/how-does-the-back-button-in-a-web-browser-work) on how the browser is supposed to work so I don't understand why the requests are being made. Sometimes over 10 requests are made.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more information?  A stack trace or something else to go off?

Comment: Are those requests relevant to the page that back button links to ??  Like, when you normally visit the page, are those requests fired ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky yes, the request are legitimate but instead of just one request, there are anywhere from 3 to 10 request being made. One thing I did notice is that the JS and CSS files are different from each set of request...could this be because the assets have not been compiled?

Comment: @Allan away from my computer, will do as soon as I get back