# What should I expect the back button to do?

Tags: dom, browser, back, browser-history

I'm working on a web app with that includes a "Search" button. We've included some code that says "when the user clicks submit, add a class to the submit button that animates it, and disable that button."

I observe that if I click "Back" from the search results page, the search page appears in its initial state: the button is not disabled, and it doesn't have the "submitting" class. This is good.

But can I rely on it? When the user clicks the "back" button in a browser, is it expected to restore the DOM as it **first** saw it, or as it **last** saw it?

**What is the expected behavior of the back button, and how well do browsers conform?**

Comment: This feels like a dumb question, given how long I've been building web apps, but I'd rather ask than not know. :)

Comment: Note: we're not doing anything to deliberately interact with history (like history.pushState())

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313788/how-does-the-back-button-in-a-web-browser-work