# How does browser back button work in web application?

Tags: null

I dont have any body regarding this. 
I have tried reading the concepts in internet but still confusing about this one please suggest how it is works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going through the pages, the URL changes. Back button basicly returns you to the previous URL (previous page).

Nowadays some web applications use the same URL all the time and reloads content dynamically - in this case the back button is nearly useless.

More informations: [How does the Back button in a web browser work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313788/how-does-the-back-button-in-a-web-browser-work)