# How to allow a user to go back on PHP page?

Tags: php

I have implemented session into my application, but I need to allow the logged in user to use the back button to go to the previous pages.
How do I make sure that the session does not expire and allows the user to view the previous page?

Here is my code

```
<?php
//Start session
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
$User = $_SESSION["User"];
//Page content
?>
```

I have started the session, when I use the back button on browser I get a page that reads session has expired. Which I do not want to happen.

Comment: that will depend on your server session configuration or if you've set a session timeout limit in your script

Comment: Maybe hyperlink to the previous (or any other page) and on that page use session_start() at the start of the code. Like @Fred-ii- mentioned, a lot depends on your session configuration. If you have some code then that you can post here then that would be helpful.

Comment: your question is unclear, post your code, given the comment you left in an answer. voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have updated my question to include my code.

Comment: there should be 2 pieces of code, for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your php at the top of each page, start your session before your opening `<html>` tag

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
```

in your php somewhere set your session variables **note this value must be serializable**

```
<?php $_SESSION["variable"] = "value"; ?>
```

then anytime you want to access that session variable you can do the following **AFTER** calling `session_start();`

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["variable"]; ?>
```

if you handle your sessions in this manner, session variables will be available on previous and future pages.

caveat:

depending on browser and headers sent from your server, when you go back a page, it reloads the page as it was in the cache so consider the following:

1. User goes to page and is does not have a session variable set
2. User does action that sets a session variable and sends them to a second page
3. User hits back button

   - User is shown the pre-session cached version of the first page
4. User refreshes page
5. User now sees the first page w/ session variable set

the reason for the hiccup is that some browsers do not always make a new request on back button sometimes it loads from the browser cache. read the very end of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313941/884453

### EDIT

You posted code above with a check to session_status first. This is incorrect. You ALWAYS need so `session_start();`

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
// User is either pulled from the session or is null
$User = $_SESSION["User"] ? !empty($_SESSION["User"]) : NULL;
//Page content
?>
```

the code for `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {` is only useful in situations where some other bit of code (usually in a framework) may have started the session already.

Comment: This is what I have done. The issue is that when I reload the page to display any calculation or content, the session does not expire. But when using the back button, the session expires. I need to be able to display all the past pages without getting this session expired message.

Comment: I updated my answer with some thoughts on the example code you posted

Comment: I am using `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {` in every page to pull user name that is stored in session, so if I used `session_start();`, I get an error saying that the session has already started.

Comment: I think the session time out is the issue I am facing, but I have no idea how to set a custom value for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up your session management correctly, you *don't need to do anything*.

However, this *correctly* depends on what kind of state you have in the session and how you manage it. Also timeouts will still apply (as they should).

Comment: I have not set any time out or anything. I am simply storing user name into session variable and using it at any places that it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript history method also for that so your session also remain same.

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```